# Can I have an iTunes library on a hard drive connected only to my wi-fi router?

Tags: iphone, itunes, network, wifi

I have both Windows and Mac laptop computers with hard drives that are too small to fit my music collection or backup iPhones.  I would like to purchase a hard drive that I can connect to my wi-fi router which can include parts of my iTunes library not on my laptop, and could be a place for me to backup my phone.  For example I was thinking about the Seagate Central 3 TB Shared Storage Ethernet External Hard Drive.  Does anyone know of a way to do what I want with this or any other product?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store your iTunes library on shared drive. Its not really any different than an external drive attached via USB or the like.

[Apple KB: iTunes for Mac: Moving your iTunes Media folder](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1449?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

If you are looking to run home sharing, or stream to an AppleTV or the like you still need a computer to handle that.